What is the meaning of "in the knee of somewhere"? Is it a common phrase in English?
I'm reading an article on Wikipedia and saw a sentence "Martigny-Ville in the knee of Valais". I understand every single word in this sentence, but just can't understand the whole sentence.
Martigny-Ville is a Swiss city, Valais is a Swiss canton. But knee is a part in the human body. How can a canton have a part in the human body? How can a city be a part in the human body?
Is it a idiom, slang or a metaphor? What does it mean?

OED knee "II.6.a. c1595– Part of a hill, tree, etc., regarded as corresponding to the knee." In this case etc=Valais. Other dictionaries are less detailed but Merriam-Webster online notes that "knee" can mean "something resembling the human knee" with examples from shipbuilding and botany. Wikipedia's definitions of knee include a riverbend and a bend in a mathematical curve.

Compare Puglia - the heel of Italy. And the Somali Peninsula - the Horn of Africa.

The history of that Wikipedia article  shows that it originated as a translation from the article in German Wikipedia, the current version of which makes mention of “Martigny-Ville im Knie des Wallis,” and Knie is German for knee.
I don’t know whether “der Knie des Wallis” is a thing in German, but it’s clear that the scrap of English you’ve asked about is a direct—and perhaps none too careful— translation.


But knee is a part in the human body. How can a canton have a part in the human body?

In which case, it must be a metaphor!
The knee is imagined as bent; forming a sharp angle. - like a human knee.
It is not a metaphor that I have heard in English, but it is clear enough.


In English I think we'd more commonly use elbow as the metaphor here, but the principle is the same.

Also, Martigny is situated on a sharp bend in the River Rhone, which may be relevant.

It is only clear if you look at a map. This is neither idiomatic English, nor meaningful in English.

The word knee can refer to a wide variety of things shaped like a knee, as any good dictionary will tell you. It's a mistake to think it only refers to the part of the human body.
Collins online dictionary says "7. anything resembling a knee in shape, such as an angular bend in a pipe". The OED's entry knee (noun) includes the definition "II.6.a. c1595– Part of a hill, tree, etc., regarded as corresponding to the knee." In this case the region of Valais, which has a bend in it - like a knee. Wikipedia notes that knee also commonly refers to a bend in a river.
Other dictionaries are less detailed but Merriam-Webster online notes that "knee" can mean "something resembling the human knee" with examples from shipbuilding and botany.  Wikipedia's definitions of knee also include a bend in a mathematical curve. Collins also allows "6. anything resembling a knee in action, such as a device pivoted to allow one member angular movement in relation to another".


Martigny-Ville in the knee of Valais

It is a geographical description.   Wikipedia says the Canton of Valais has a height of 4634m.

Valais
Canton of Valais
Highest point   4,634 m (15,203 ft): Monte Rosa

and that

[Martigny] lies at an elevation of 471 meters (1,545 ft)

The writer has used knee to describe this proportion.
Martigny

This is highly unlikely to be a reference to height. There must be a lot of other places that are more or less at the same height as Martigny.
